# Getting the Target Value from a Form Stored as JS Variable

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to let the user select a value from a dropdown selector, which in turn will conditionally load a second dropdown selector. Once both fields have a value, a link will appear that has been dynamically generated from those two values.

For example: User selects "audi" from first form, which shows the audi form, then they select "r8" from the second form, which would produce [www.example.com/**audi**/**r8**/](http://www.example.com/**audi**/**r8**/)

However, it seems that I can't get the event.target.value of the second dropdown; I'm assuming because when the script loads the value isn't there.

How would I go about writing this so I could get both values, then fill it into a link?

```
    <form>
    <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Car</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
    </select>
  </form>
<br><br>

<div class="model-field" id="model-field"></div>

<div class="button-field">
  <h4>link:</h4>
  <p id="button-field"></p>
</div>

  <script>

    var audiForm = '<form class="audi-model">' + 
          '<select name="audi-model" id="audi-model">' +
          '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Audi model</option>' +
            '<option value="a4">A4</option>' +
            '<option value="a5">A5</option>' +
            '<option value="r8">r8</option>' +
          '</select>' +
        '</form>';

    var vwForm = '<form class="vw-model">'  +
    '<select name="vw-model" id="vw-model">' +
    '<option value="" disabled selected>Select VW model</option>' +
      '<option value="jetta">Jetta</option>' +
      '<option value="passat">Passat</option>' +
    '</select>' +
  '</form>';

    var carsForm = document.getElementById("cars");
    if (carsForm) carsForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var carType = (event.target.value);
      console.log(carType);
        if(event.target.value == 'audi') {
          document.getElementById("model-field").innerHTML = audiForm;
        }
        if(event.target.value == 'volkswagen') {
          document.getElementById("model-field").innerHTML = vwForm;
        }
    });
    
    var audiModelForm = document.getElementById("audi-model");
    if (audiModelForm) audiModelForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var audiModel = event.target.value;
      console.log(audiModel); // Doesn't work as the above line is likely null
      var link = '<h4>' + carType + '/' + audiModel + '</h4>';
      console.log(link);
      document.getElementById("button-field").innerHTML = link;
    });


    var vwModelForm = document.getElementById("vw-model");
    if (vwModelForm) vwModelForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var vwModel = event.target.value;
      console.log(vwModel);  // Doesn't work as the above line is likely null
      var link = '<h4>' + carType + '/' + vwModel + '</h4>';
      console.log(link);
      document.getElementById("button-field").innerHTML = link;
    });
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to store the options in a javascript object, and just auto fill in the select as needed. This will allow you to easily update the system to accept more makes and models.

```js
var data = {
"audi": ["a4","a5","r8"],
"volkswagen": ["Bug","Jetta","Golf"]
};

var make = document.querySelector("#cars");
var model = document.querySelector("#model");
var link = document.querySelector("#link");
make.addEventListener("change",function(){
if(make.value != ""){
  var models = data[make.value];
  var length = model.options.length;
  for (i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {model.options[i] = null;}
  link.innerHTML = "";
  
  let opt= document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = "Select " + make.value + " Model";
   opt.value = "";
  model.appendChild(opt);
  
  models.forEach(function(k,v){
   let opt= document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = k;
   opt.value = k;
    model.appendChild(opt);
  });
  }
});

model.addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(model.value != ""){
     link.innerHTML = '<h4>' + make.value + '/' + model.value + '</h4>';
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Car</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  </select>
  <select name="model" id="model"></select>
</form>
<div id="link">

</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. If I wanted to add a third form that adds also conditionally loads based on make value (audi/a4/[a,b,c,d]) or (vw/jetta/[e,f,g]), how would I structure that object? It seems like I'd have to convert the model array into new objects?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code attempts to find and set up an event handler for the second dropdown before it gets created. Moving that code so that it is within the first event handler makes it work.

```html
<form>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Car</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br><br>

<div class="model-field" id="model-field"></div>

<div class="button-field">
  <h1>link:</h1>
  <p id="button-field"></p>
</div>

  <script>

    var audiForm = '<select name="audi-model" id="audi-model">' +
          '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Audi model</option>' +
            '<option value="a4">A4</option>' +
            '<option value="a5">A5</option>' +
            '<option value="r8">r8</option>' +
          '</select>' +
        '</form>';

    var vwForm = '<select name="vw-model" id="vw-model">' +
    '<option value="" disabled selected>Select VW model</option>' +
      '<option value="jetta">Jetta</option>' +
      '<option value="passat">Passat</option>' +
    '</select>' +
  '</form>';

    var carsForm = document.getElementById("cars");
    if (carsForm) carsForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var carType = (event.target.value);
      console.log(carType);
        if(event.target.value == 'audi') {
          document.getElementById("model-field").innerHTML = audiForm;
        }
        if(event.target.value == 'volkswagen') {
          document.getElementById("model-field").innerHTML = vwForm;
        }
        
        var audiModelForm = document.getElementById("audi-model");
        if (audiModelForm) {
          audiModelForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            var audiModel = event.target.value;
            console.log(audiModel);
            var link = '<h4>' + carType + '/' + audiModel + '</h4>';
            console.log(link);
            document.getElementById("button-field").innerHTML = link;
         });
         }
    });
   

    var vwModelForm = document.getElementById("vw-model");
    if (vwModelForm) vwModelForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      var vwModel = event.target.value;
      console.log(vwModel);  // Doesn't work as the above line is likely null
      var link = '<h4>' + carType + '/' + vwModel + '</h4>';
      console.log(link);
      document.getElementById("button-field").innerHTML = link;
    });
    
    </script>
```

But really, a better solution is to have the `select` already statically built from the start, but just hidden. Then, you can set up its handler right away, but only populate its `option` elements after the first selection has been made. You'll also only need one secondary `select` for whatever set of `option` elements are relevant based on the first choice.

Also, you shouldn't be creating `form` elements that wrap each `select`. If you are going to submit this data somewhere, you just want one `form` around all the form elements. And, if not, you don't need a `form` at all.

Lastly, don't use HTML heading elements because of the size that they make your text. You can't have an `h4` unless you've already got an `h3`. Use CSS to style your text.

```js
var audi = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select Audi model</option>' +
            '<option value="a4">A4</option>' +
            '<option value="a5">A5</option>' +
            '<option value="r8">r8</option>';

var vw = '<option value="" disabled selected>Select VW model</option>' +
      '<option value="jetta">Jetta</option>' +
      '<option value="passat">Passat</option>';

var cars = document.getElementById("cars");
var models = document.getElementById("models");

cars.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if(event.target.value == 'audi') {
    models.innerHTML = audi;
  } else if(event.target.value == 'volkswagen') {
   models.innerHTML = vw;
  }
  models.classList.remove("hidden"); // Time to show the second list
});
   
models.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var link = '<h1>' + cars.value + '/' + models.value + '</h1>';
  console.log(link);
  document.getElementById("button-field").innerHTML = link;
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
h1 { font-size:.8em;}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Car</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
  </select>

  <div class="model-field" id="model-field">
    <select name="models" id="models" class="hidden"></select>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="button-field">
  <h1>link:</h1>
  <p id="button-field"></p>
</div>
```